# A panel scrollbars doesn't work with a label content

Tags: asp.net, firefox, scrollbar, panel

I am trying to put a Label control within a panel control. the panel control is supposed to enable the user scroll down when the label content grows bigger than the panel capacity.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EventReviewPage.aspx.cs"
Inherits="EventReviewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Event Log: "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLog" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="True" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Source: "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSource" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdGet" runat="server" Text="Get Records" OnClick="cmdGet_Click" />
 </div>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ScrollBars="Vertical">
    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
 </asp:Panel>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asp:Panel` warps the text with a div, but you do not have specify a height for this panel, so their height is always fit the height of your data, and thats why you do not see scroll bar for that div.

If you set both height and width you see the scroll bar.

For example

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
      ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="80px" Width="180px">
```